# Regex to match two factors in one?

Tags: regex

Using `<div dir=.*?>` works fine to match `<div dir="auto">`.

[image]

However, why does `<div dir=.*?><br \/>` not match `<div dir="auto"><br />`?

[image]

Code: https://regex101.com/r/5pP38n/1

Comment: Because it's inside another match, and a regexp won't return overlapping matches.

Comment: As per the [*How to ask* guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/251362#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regexp starts matching at the first `<div dir=` in the input. Then it looks for the next `><br \/>` in the input. `.*?` will match everything between them, which is

```
"auto">Please  sir my youtube channel delete&nbsp;<div dir="auto"
```

You don't match `<div dir="auto"><br />` because it's contained inside this match, and a regexp doesn't return overlapping matches.

If you don't want `.*?` to match across multiple tags, you can use `[^>]*` instead.

```
<div dir=[^>]*><br \/>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Digv8r/1)